# Can't install Imager On Mac

Tags: perl, module, cpan

I have been struggling to install Cpan Module 'Imager' and 'Imager::File::PNG' on Mac By Cpanm

```
cpanm --look Imager
```

and
'Imager::File::PNG' need 'libpng' library
so, i try to install 'libpng' by homebrew

```
brew install libpng
```

...ok.(but this libpng library already has been installed on My Mac)

then,

```
IM_INCPATH=/usr/X11/include IM_LIBPATH=/usr/X11/lib perl Makefile.PL
```

indicate include path and library path,and do 'perl Makefile.PL'

but,below is result

Libraries found:

```
FT2
JPEG
```

Libraries *not* found:

```
GIF
PNG
T1
TIFF
Win32
```

looking error code...

```
PNG: v1.5: includes found - libraries found
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png15'
```

Can't link/include 'png15' ????
I can't resolve this problem by myself.
please give me your support.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The paths are wrong. Homebrew installs to `/usr/local/Cellar`.

Comment: Do know what the paths have to be? `/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.34/include`  and `lib` do not work.